# scp returns Exit status 1

Tags: ssh, samba, scp

In a LAN I have two PC, both running Ubuntu 13.04.

There is a directory which is in a shared folder (samba, guest access) in the first PC.
I have tried to copy this directory to the second PC through nautilus (the file browser in which I can see the shared folder)... I get a timeout error and after the samba share is unavailable.

Then I tried to copy with scp... it stopped again : and after I cannot connect with ssh at all till I reboot the machine. More surprising the samba share is also unavailable after this scp problem.

I tried a scp in verbose mode and that is what I got :

```
scp: /home/yvesu/Public/Alexandre/002/pmvs/models/option-0008.pset: Input/output error
Sending file modes: C0744 205850157 option-0009.patch
Sink: C0744 205850157 option-0009.patch
option-0009.patch                                                100%  196MB  98.2MB/s   00:02    
scp: /home/yvesu/Public/Alexandre/002/pmvs/models/option-0009.patch: Input/output error
Sending file modes: C0744 129092129 option-0005.pset
Sink: C0744 129092129 option-0005.pset
option-0005.pset                                                 100%  123MB  61.6MB/s   00:02    
scp: /home/yvesu/Public/Alexandre/002/pmvs/models/option-0005.pset: Input/output error
Sending file modes: C0744 228669306 option-0006.ply
Sink: C0744 228669306 option-0006.ply
option-0006.ply                                                  100%  218MB  54.5MB/s   00:04    
scp: /home/yvesu/Public/Alexandre/002/pmvs/models/option-0006.ply: Input/output error
Sending file modes: C0744 84462440 option-0001.pset
Sink: C0744 84462440 option-0001.pset
option-0001.pset                                                 100%   81MB  80.6MB/s   00:01    
scp: /home/yvesu/Public/Alexandre/002/pmvs/models/option-0001.pset: Input/output error
Sink: E
Sending file modes: C0744 874 centers-0010.ply
Sink: C0744 874 centers-0010.ply
centers-0010.ply                                                 100%  874     0.9KB/s   00:00    
scp: /home/yvesu/Public/Alexandre/002/pmvs/centers-0010.ply: Input/output error
Sending file modes: C0744 384 option-0009
Sink: C0744 384 option-0009
option-0009                                                      100%  384     0.4KB/s   00:00    
scp: /home/yvesu/Public/Alexandre/002/pmvs/option-0009: Input/output error
Sink: E
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype eow@openssh.com reply 0
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
debug1: fd 0 clearing O_NONBLOCK
debug1: fd 1 clearing O_NONBLOCK
Transferred: sent 3586000, received 13047756680 bytes, in 283.6 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 12646.3, received 46013798.3
debug1: Exit status 1
```

After this when I try to connect with ssh :

```
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

And When I double click on the samba share :

```
Unable to access location
Failed to mount Windows share: Connection timed out
```

The HDD, where the directory is, is brand new. With the disks utility It shows nothing with the SMART data self tests.

Ideas ?

Comment: use `-v` front of `scp`, it causes scp act in `verbose mode`.

Comment: That's what have done. I said that I tried a scp in verbose mode. I think it is deeper than that : I try a copy between two HDD from the same machine and I got a black screen :S. I' m totally new maybe it is because I share data which is on the same HDD as the system... and when I transfert it blocks something... during transfer computer is really slow, almost unusable.

Comment: They are 3To WD caviar green... slow ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got an input output error after an `ls`, this plus black screen as mentioned in my comment... It has to be HDD related.

I installed ubuntu on another HDD, same brand, same model... everything works like a charm.